# Rails Model Associations with has_many, through, class_name and where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

Looking for a little help with rails associations. I have three Models. User, Attendee and Meeting and I would like to return a users attending Meetings based on their roles (which is under the attendee model). However I can't figure out how to return the user with a where clause.

My code currently returns the `Attendee` and then I look up the `User` object but I would love it if there was I way I could make it return the `User` object without having to look it up after the call.

```
class Meeting

  has_one :owner, -> { where role: 'owner' }, class_name: 'Attendee'
  has_one :mentor, -> { where role: 'mentor' }, class_name: 'Attendee'
  has_many :mentees, -> { where role: 'mentee' }, class_name: 'Attendee'

end
```

The other associations I have are as follows

```
  has_many :users, through: :attendees
  has_many :attendees, dependent: :destroy
```

Is this possible? Any input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood you correctly. Have you tried this and is this what you need?

```
class Meeting
  has_one :owner, -> { where role: 'owner' }, class_name: 'Attendee'
  has_one :mentor, -> { where role: 'mentor' }, class_name: 'Attendee'
  has_many :mentees, -> { where role: 'mentee' }, class_name: 'Attendee'

  has_one :owner_user, through: :owner, source: :user
  has_one :mentor_user, through: :mentor, source: :user
  has_many :mentees_users, through: :mentees, source: :user
end
```

Comment: Thanks Chumakoff, didn't know things worked like that! It was just missing one thing on the end of each line `source: :user`